# Magento 2 Email Confirmation Not Working

Tags: magento2, email, password-recovery

I have a problem with `Magento 2.2.5.`
All the links sent on email like the `email confirmation link` or the `password reset link` is not working.

The problem is that is my website is my_website.com then these links belong to a subdomain `links.my_website.com.`

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong in the configuration?

Comment: All the links should be matched with domain then these can work.

Comment: I am facing the same issue in the Magento 1.9. Can anyone plz help?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/137012)